# error Task :react-native-community_datetimepicker:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to upgrade react native from v0.69.5 to v0.72.3 with the new architecture on my app in a monorepo with yarn, but I'm getting the following error when running yarn `react-native run-android`

```
> Task :react-native-community_datetimepicker:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins. 

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

Execution optimizations have been disabled for 10 invalid unit(s) of work during this build to ensure correctness.
Please consult deprecation warnings for more details.
236 actionable tasks: 227 executed, 9 up-to-date

info  Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correctly, by running react-native doctor. To read more about doctor command visit: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-doctor/README.md#doctor

No modules to process in combine-js-to-schema-cli. If this is unexpected, please check if you set up your NativeComponent correctly. See combine-js-to-schema.js for how codegen finds modules.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
No modules to process in combine-js-to-schema-cli. If this is unexpected, please check if you set up your NativeComponent correctly. See combine-js-to-schema.js for how codegen finds modules.
No modules to process in combine-js-to-schema-cli. If this is unexpected, please check if you set up your NativeComponent correctly. See combine-js-to-schema.js for how codegen finds modules.
No modules to process in combine-js-to-schema-cli. If this is unexpected, please check if you set up your NativeComponent correctly. See combine-js-to-schema.js for how codegen finds modules.
Note: C:\Users\thiago_gomes\Documents\OmniJs\node_modules\lottie-react-native\src\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\lottie\LottieAnimationViewManager.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Users\thiago_gomes\Documents\OmniJs\node_modules\lottie-react-native\src\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\lottie\LottieAnimationViewManager.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: C:\Users\thiago_gomes\Documents\OmniJs\node_modules\@react-native-clipboard\clipboard\android\src\main\java\com\reactnativecommunity\clipboard\ClipboardModule.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Users\thiago_gomes\Documents\OmniJs\node_modules\@react-native-community\checkbox\android\src\main\java\com\reactnativecommunity\checkbox\ReactCheckBoxEvent.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
C:\Users\thiago_gomes\Documents\OmniJs\node_modules\@react-native-community\datetimepicker\android\src\main\java\com\reactcommunity\rndatetimepicker\DatePickerModule.java:35: error: cannot find symbol
public class DatePickerModule extends NativeModuleDatePickerSpec {
                                      ^
  symbol: class NativeModuleDatePickerSpec
C:\Users\thiago_gomes\Documents\OmniJs\node_modules\@react-native-community\datetimepicker\android\src\main\java\com\reactcommunity\rndatetimepicker\TimePickerModule.java:33: error: cannot find symbol
public class TimePickerModule extends NativeModuleTimePickerSpec {
                                      ^
  symbol: class NativeModuleTimePickerSpec
C:\Users\thiago_gomes\Documents\OmniJs\node_modules\@react-native-community\datetimepicker\android\src\main\java\com\reactcommunity\rndatetimepicker\DatePickerModule.java:44: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
  @Override
  ^
C:\Users\thiago_gomes\Documents\OmniJs\node_modules\@react-native-community\datetimepicker\android\src\main\java\com\reactcommunity\rndatetimepicker\DatePickerModule.java:62: error: cannot find symbol
      if (!mPromiseResolved && getReactApplicationContext().hasActiveReactInstance()) {
                               ^
  symbol:   method getReactApplicationContext()
  location: class DatePickerModule.DatePickerDialogListener
C:\Users\thiago_gomes\Documents\OmniJs\node_modules\@react-native-community\datetimepicker\android\src\main\java\com\reactcommunity\rndatetimepicker\DatePickerModule.java:96: error: cannot find symbol
      if (!mPromiseResolved && getReactApplicationContext().hasActiveReactInstance()) {
                               ^
  symbol:   method getReactApplicationContext()
  location: class DatePickerModule.DatePickerDialogListener
C:\Users\thiago_gomes\Documents\OmniJs\node_modules\@react-native-community\datetimepicker\android\src\main\java\com\reactcommunity\rndatetimepicker\DatePickerModule.java:106: error: cannot find symbol
      if (!mPromiseResolved && getReactApplicationContext().hasActiveReactInstance()) {
                               ^
  symbol:   method getReactApplicationContext()
  location: class DatePickerModule.DatePickerDialogListener
C:\Users\thiago_gomes\Documents\OmniJs\node_modules\@react-native-community\datetimepicker\android\src\main\java\com\reactcommunity\rndatetimepicker\DatePickerModule.java:117: error: cannot find symbol
    FragmentActivity activity = (FragmentActivity) getCurrentActivity();
                                                   ^
  symbol:   method getCurrentActivity()
  location: class DatePickerModule
C:\Users\thiago_gomes\Documents\OmniJs\node_modules\@react-native-community\datetimepicker\android\src\main\java\com\reactcommunity\rndatetimepicker\DatePickerModule.java:150: error: cannot find symbol
    FragmentActivity activity = (FragmentActivity) getCurrentActivity();
                                                   ^
  symbol:   method getCurrentActivity()
  location: class DatePickerModule
C:\Users\thiago_gomes\Documents\OmniJs\node_modules\@react-native-community\datetimepicker\android\src\main\java\com\reactcommunity\rndatetimepicker\RNDateTimePickerPackage.java:20: error: incompatible types: DatePickerModule cannot be converted to NativeModule
      return new DatePickerModule(reactContext);
             ^
C:\Users\thiago_gomes\Documents\OmniJs\node_modules\@react-native-community\datetimepicker\android\src\main\java\com\reactcommunity\rndatetimepicker\RNDateTimePickerPackage.java:22: error: incompatible types: TimePickerModule cannot be converted to NativeModule
      return new TimePickerModule(reactContext);
             ^
C:\Users\thiago_gomes\Documents\OmniJs\node_modules\@react-native-community\datetimepicker\android\src\main\java\com\reactcommunity\rndatetimepicker\TimePickerModule.java:43: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
  @Override
  ^
C:\Users\thiago_gomes\Documents\OmniJs\node_modules\@react-native-community\datetimepicker\android\src\main\java\com\reactcommunity\rndatetimepicker\TimePickerModule.java:58: error: cannot find symbol
      if (!mPromiseResolved && getReactApplicationContext().hasActiveReactInstance()) {
                               ^
  symbol:   method getReactApplicationContext()
  location: class TimePickerModule.TimePickerDialogListener
C:\Users\thiago_gomes\Documents\OmniJs\node_modules\@react-native-community\datetimepicker\android\src\main\java\com\reactcommunity\rndatetimepicker\TimePickerModule.java:70: error: cannot find symbol
      if (!mPromiseResolved && getReactApplicationContext().hasActiveReactInstance()) {
                               ^
  symbol:   method getReactApplicationContext()
  location: class TimePickerModule.TimePickerDialogListener
C:\Users\thiago_gomes\Documents\OmniJs\node_modules\@react-native-community\datetimepicker\android\src\main\java\com\reactcommunity\rndatetimepicker\TimePickerModule.java:80: error: cannot find symbol
      if (!mPromiseResolved && getReactApplicationContext().hasActiveReactInstance()) {
                               ^
  symbol:   method getReactApplicationContext()
  location: class TimePickerModule.TimePickerDialogListener
C:\Users\thiago_gomes\Documents\OmniJs\node_modules\@react-native-community\datetimepicker\android\src\main\java\com\reactcommunity\rndatetimepicker\TimePickerModule.java:91: error: cannot find symbol
    FragmentActivity activity = (FragmentActivity) getCurrentActivity();
                                                   ^
  symbol:   method getCurrentActivity()
  location: class TimePickerModule
C:\Users\thiago_gomes\Documents\OmniJs\node_modules\@react-native-community\datetimepicker\android\src\main\java\com\reactcommunity\rndatetimepicker\TimePickerModule.java:97: error: cannot find symbol
    FragmentActivity activity = (FragmentActivity) getCurrentActivity();
                                                   ^
  symbol:   method getCurrentActivity()
  location: class TimePickerModule
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
16 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-community_datetimepicker:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

I already tried to clean the gradle, reinstall the packages and start over but I didn't get any success
This is my android/buil.gradle file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "33.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 33
        // We use NDK 23 which has both M1 support and is the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
        ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
        classpath("com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4")
    }
}
```